# Root su command

Tags: java, android, root

I'm developing an application that works with rooted devices too.

I have two questions:

1. When I launch the application, it checks for root, the SuperUser dialog appears, I click on Accept then 'Remember my Choice' later, I run a command:

   ```
   Process process;
   try {
     process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] 
                {"su", "-c", "rm -r /data/data"});
     prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 
                Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
     prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
     stopSelf();
   ```

   then here again the SuperUser dialog appears. Why is it appearing more than once for the same application? I checked "Remember My Choice".
2. I'm using

   ```
   process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
               {"su", "-c", "rm -r /data/data"});
   ```

Is there any way to add exceptions, e.g. `Do not delete "com.My.App"`?

Comment: when an Answer is Helpful to my Problem , then i Accept it , But i will be 'less' Difficult to Accept Answers Now ...

Answer (score 1):

You are removing /data/data and all subdirectories of it. This is the place where applications are storing the app private data, and for sure the SuperUser isstoring in here the list of authorized applications.

I believe you already guess what's happenig ... you are removing your own authorization.

You need to add an exception to the superUser.

To add an exception, I couldn't find a straightforward solution, as only limited shell commands are available. If you install busybox it would give you opportunity to use the grep command to parse the input and exclude the lines you want.

Alternatively, you can do it programmatically using the following approach:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "ls /data/data"}); 

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

String line; 
ArrayList<String>  files = new ArrayList<String>();
files.add("su");
files.add("-c");
files.add("rm -r");

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
  //test if you want to exclude the file before you add it
  files.add("/data/data/" + line);
}
//issue a new command to remove the directories
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(files.toArray(new String[0])); //changed this line
```

Hope it helped.

--EDITED--

The code bellow is working fine on a rooted device. The final command being issued is also a `ls`, as I don't want to remove my files, but you can just replace it by anything else (see comments in file).

```
private void execCmd(){
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "ls /data/data"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

    String line; 
    ArrayList<String>  files = new ArrayList<String>();
    files.add("su");
    files.add("-c");
//      files.add("rm -r");  //Uncomment this line and comment the line bellow for real delete 
    files.add("ls"); 

    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
          //test if you want to exclude the file before you add it
          files.add("/data/data/" + line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //comment lines bellow to stop logging the command being sent
    Log.d(TAG, "Command size: " + files.size());
    for(int i=0; i< files.size(); i++)
        Log.d(TAG, "Cmd[" + i + "]: " + files.get(i));

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(files.toArray(new String[0]));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //changed this line
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks you for you Great and usefull answer , but i have an Error on this line : process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(files.toArray()); Error : The method exec(String[]) in the type Runtime is not applicable for the arguments (Object[]) also , i havnt SuperUser Elite Version to Save Allowed Applications ...

Comment: You are right, I missed the argument. I've changed the line with the issue.

Comment: ok it look Like its try to Run All Command at the same time or Permission Denied ? its worked fine to delete data with my Method Take a look at LogCat http://pastebin.com/kv7chv5h

Comment: It looks like the su command needs to be in a separate array index. Try it with the changes I've done above;

Comment: First, it will not work on a emulator (unless you root it as well). Secondly, I tested it on my device and it worked to the point that it constructed the remove command with all the directories as parameters (I put a breakpoint here). You will need to debug it yourself from here on, as I'm not willing to delete all my data. Try to run the command builded directly in a adb shell and check it it works or if it requires any tweaking.

Comment: ok i never use Emulator , im Using my Galaxy s2 i9100G running Cyanogen 10 , secondly , it run the Command Ok , but it does not Delete Data , i have also Rebooted my Device to Check . Also Thanks you for your Help .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17355/discussion-between-celb-and-luis)

Comment: Still No Work , Any Help Luis ? Thanks